# How to access a field's value in an object using reflection

Tags: java, exception, reflection, illegalaccessexception

**My Question:** How to overcome an `IllegalAccessException` to access the value of an object's field using reflection.

**Expansion:** I'm trying to learn about reflection to make some of my projects more generic. I'm running into an `IllegalAccessException` when trying to call `field.getValue(object)` to get the value of that field in that object. I can get the name and type just fine.

If I change the declaration from `private` to `public` then this works fine. But in an effort to follow the "rules" of encapsulation I don't want to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**My Code:**

```
package main;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Tester {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    new Tester().reflectionTest();
  }

  public void reflectionTest() throws Exception {
    Person person = new Person("John Doe", "555-123-4567", "Rover");
    Field[] fields = person.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
      System.out.println("Field Name: " + field.getName());
      System.out.println("Field Type: " + field.getType());
      System.out.println("Field Value: " + field.get(person));
      //The line above throws: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class main.Tester can not access a member of class main.Tester$Person with modifiers "private final"
    }
  }

  public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String phoneNumber;
    private final String dogsName;

    public Person(String name, String phoneNumber, String dogsName) {
      this.name = name;
      this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
      this.dogsName = dogsName;
    }
  }
}
```

**The Output:**

```
run:
Field Name: name
Field Type: class java.lang.String
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class main.Tester can not access a member of class main.Tester$Person with modifiers "private final"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.doSecurityCheck(Field.java:983)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:927)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:372)
    at main.Tester.reflectionTest(Tester.java:17)
    at main.Tester.main(Tester.java:8)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: `field.setAccessible(true);`

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Before you `get` a private field, you need to call `setAccessible(true);` on the corresponding field:

```
for (Field field : fields) {
    field.setAccessible(true); // Additional line
    System.out.println("Field Name: " + field.getName());
    System.out.println("Field Type: " + field.getType());
    System.out.println("Field Value: " + field.get(person));
}
```

Answer (score 21):

By default you are not allowed to read non-public fields, but simply invoking `field.setAccessible(true);` will allow access. In other words, your code should say

```
for (Field field : fields) {
  field.setAccessible(true);
  // ...
}
```