# How do I determine if a field is private or protected using reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784901/5450594), I've gathered you can't access a private field without setting `setAccessible(true)`. I could determine if a field is public or not with `isAccessible()`. However, how would I determine if it were public or private?

Comment: Check the [modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`Field.getModifiers()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getModifiers%28%29) to get the field modifiers. You can then use [`Modifier.is*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) to find out :

```
int modifiers = field.getModifiers();

if(Modifier.isProtected(modifiers)) {
  // protected
}
else if(Modifier.isPrivate(modifiers)) {
  // private 
}
```

Comment: Java does not allow you to write `if(int)`.

Answer (score 4):

Given this class

```
class MyClass {
  public String v1;
  protected String v2;
  private String v3;
}
```

You can check the modifiers this way

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

Field field;
int modifier;

field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("v1");
modifier = field.getModifiers();
System.out.println(Modifier.toString(modifier));

field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("v2");
modifier = field.getModifiers();
System.out.println(Modifier.toString(modifier));

field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("v3");
modifier = field.getModifiers();
System.out.println(Modifier.toString(modifier));
```

Prints out:

```
public
protected
private
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong. You don't need reflection to access public fields. You can access them directly that's why they are public in the first place.

Besides that you can use `getModifiers` and parse that. See [Retrieving and Parsing Field Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html)

Comment: I think OP want to know if a random variable is public/protected/private using reflection, not access the value  of that variable. Could be used to create a home made documentation ;)

Comment: You're correct. I meant to put 'private' instead of 'public'. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Model {
    public int pub;
    private int priv;
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field[] fields = Model.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Field field = fields[i];
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " : " + Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers()));
        }
    }
```